# Связь многие ко многим с наложением ограничений

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть следующие таблицы в бд

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Items (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  OperationId INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Items_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Items
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Items_Operations_Id FOREIGN KEY (OperationId) REFERENCES dbo.Operations (Id)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Assemblies (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  ParentId INT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Assemblies_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Assemblies
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Assemblies_Assemblies_Id FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES dbo.Assemblies (Id)
GO
```

Мне необходимо сохранять связь между `Item` & `Assembly`, при добавлении к связи необходимо заполнить несколько полей(список полей и их типы в таблице ниже)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tempTable (
  Position VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Overhang DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  Runtime DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  AmountCuttingEdge INT NULL,
  AmountPlates INT NULL,
  Durability DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  Note VARCHAR(50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Первоначально я предполагал добавить в `tempTable` поля `ItemId`, `AssemblyId` и сделать *составной ключ* из этих полей плюс поле `Position` что бы обеспечить *уникальность*, но как оказалось этого не достаточно: необходимо так же иметь возможность указать *сборку* с заданными параметрами(`Position`, `Overhang`, ...) для нескольких итемов.

Если бы параметры *сборки* хранились в таблице `Assemblies` то я бы создал промежуточную таблицу с полями `ItemId` & `AssemblyId`. но для одной и той же сборки данные параметры могут меняться(это зависит от итема). Поэтому я хочу вынести их(параметры) в отдельную таблицу, но в этом случае не знаю как создать *связь* между этими данными?

Подскажите как сделать связь вида многие ко многим в данном описанном случае.

Comment: Не очень понятно откуда тут ноги растут, надо предметную область лучше понимать что бы правильно ответить. Пока назревает выделить эти поля как и вы в отдельную таблицу (только назвать ее конечно не tempTable, а так что бы было ясно что это) в этой таблице завести собственный ID (primary), добавить в нее поле AssemblyID, если эти параметры больше к сборке относятся и завести еще одну таблицу в которой будут ID-итема и ID сущности из той таблицы (что у вас temp)

Comment: это для программистов управляющих программ, т.к. сказать менеджер управляющих программ. Итем это Управляющая программа, Сборка это некоторый набор инструментов(сверла, фрезы и т.п.) в каждой программе может быть использовано от 1 до n сборок

Comment: Так а вот эти дополнительные поля (которые в tempTable), это свойства чего

Comment: @Mike  поля в `tempTable` это параметры сборки(вылет, время работы) применимы к конкретной сборке в конкретной УП

Comment: @Mike т.е. у той же сборки часть/все значения этих полей могут меняться

Comment: Видимо не к "конкретной сборке", а то бы ваша  первая идея была бы верной, а скажем так "параметры сборки для нескольких УП". Тогда выглядит как я в первом коменте написал, создаем таблицу "Параметры сборки", включаем в нее AssemblyID и делаем таблицу связи ItemID, ID-параметров-сборки. Но тут надо смотреть что происходит если какой то 1 параметр поменялся, он меняется сразу для всех итемов к которым данные параметры относились или может понятся только для части и тогда придется создавать новую запись параметров. Если второе - то тогда как вы изначально подумали и реализовать копирование

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56085/discussion-between-bald-and-mike).

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю две таблицы:

- Таблица характеристик связки(AI_link_characteristics)

  - id
  - Position
  - Durability
  - etc
- Таблица связки(AI_links):

  - assembly_id -> Assemblies.id
  - item_id -> Items.id
  - ai_link_id -> AI_link_characteristics.id
  - Primary key(assembly_id, item_id) // Или отдельный автоинкремент id