# Дизайн бд для менеджера технологических процессов

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Есть экземпляр класса `Item` который представляет из себя некоторый технологический процесс(управляющая программа для станка ЧПУ), для корректного выполнения которого необходимы некоторые ресурсы(инструмент, который сгруппирован в некоторый набор - *сборка*). Мне необходимо *связать* УП и набор инструмента со следующими ограничениями:

1. В одной УП может быть использовано от 1 до n *сборок* так и *сборка*  может быть использована в нескольких УП.
2. Для *сборки* есть как общие параметры(время работы, комментарий) так и параметры которые задаются для каждого инструмента входящего в сборку(например вылет инструмента, стойкость)

На основании этих данных будет необходимо формировать печатную форму, получить список инструментов участвующих в технологическом процессе, и т.п.

Для реализации этого я предполагаю использовать следующую структуру таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Items (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Items_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Tools (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Tools_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Assemblies (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  ParentId INT NULL,
  ToolId INT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Assemblies_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Assemblies
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Assemblies_Assemblies_Id FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES dbo.Assemblies (Id)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Assemblies
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Assemblies_Tools_Id FOREIGN KEY (ToolId) REFERENCES dbo.Tools (Id)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.AssemblyParameters (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  AssemblyId INT NOT NULL,
  Position DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  Runtime DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  Note NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_ParameterizedAssemblies_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.AssemblyParameters
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ParameterizedAssemblies_Assemblies_Id FOREIGN KEY (AssemblyId) REFERENCES dbo.Assemblies (Id)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ToolParametersOfAssemblies (
  AssemblyParameterId INT NOT NULL,
  ToolId INT NOT NULL,
  Overhang DECIMAL NULL,
  AmountCuttingEdge INT NULL,
  AmountPlates INT NULL,
  Durability DECIMAL NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_ToolParametersOfAssemblies PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AssemblyParameterId, ToolId)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ToolParametersOfAssemblies
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ToolParametersOfAssemblies_AssemblyParameters_Id FOREIGN KEY (AssemblyParameterId) REFERENCES dbo.AssemblyParameters (Id)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ToolParametersOfAssemblies
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ToolParametersOfAssemblies_Tools_Id FOREIGN KEY (ToolId) REFERENCES dbo.Tools (Id)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ItemParameterizedAssembly (
  ItemId INT NOT NULL,
  ParameterizedAssemblyId INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_ItemParameterizedAssembly PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ItemId, ParameterizedAssemblyId)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ItemParameterizedAssembly
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ItemParameterizedAssembly_Items_Id FOREIGN KEY (ItemId) REFERENCES dbo.Items (Id)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ItemParameterizedAssembly
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ItemParameterizedAssembly_ParameterizedAssemblies_Id FOREIGN KEY (ParameterizedAssemblyId) REFERENCES dbo.AssemblyParameters (Id)
GO
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите правильно ли спроектировал таблицы. Критика приветствуется

P.S.
Связанные вопросы:

- [Как проверить “составной” объект на уникальность?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575866/179270)
- [Связь многие ко многим с наложением ограничений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/644630/179270)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62839/discussion-on-question-by-bald------).

Comment: А почему не отобразить схему БД в виде диаграммы, это гораздо легче воспринимается?

Comment: @sp7 добавил диаграмму